# How can I use LokiJs in the browser?

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I suspect this is a bit of a simple question, as I'm not very experienced with the frontend.

I'm trying to use lokijs as a datastore in a browser app, but I can't get it to run. I have `<script src="lib/lokijs/src/loki-angular.js"></script>` in my html, and

```
var db = new loki('test');
var users = db.addCollection('users');
users.insert({
  name: 'joe'
});

console.log(users.data);
```

in my js as a trivial test. However, I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: loki is not defined`. Please let me know where' I'm going wrong, and I apologize if this is something stupid!

Comment: Are you using angular? I don't think we have enough details to really help you on this one. But in general, If you are not using anything like angular or react, you would include the lokijs js file on your page. If you are using react, you would import the file so webpack bundles it. For angular, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey Cadmium, thanks for the help! Not using angular or react -- when you say include the lokijs file, what do you mean exactly beyond the script? If there's a resource that explains this thoroughly (as I'm guessing it's a dumb question), could you point me that way?

Comment: Absolutely not a dumb question, I think you are just a step or two from getting to the root of the issue. I’ll try to post an example when I get the chance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Upon further inspection the problem you had was even simpler than I suspected. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off. You mention you are referencing `loki-angular.js` in your html, however you should be referencing `lib/lokijs/build/lokijs.min.js` or even reference it from a cdn if you don't want to involve npm, I know cdnjs has it.

With that your example should run just fine.